# pyqt5 GUI looks different in raspberry pi than in QtCreator with groupbox

Tags: raspberry-pi, pyqt5

I am creating a GUI in QtCreator under windows, then converting the .ui file to .py with pyuic5 then moving the generated .py file to raspberry. but the GUI looks very different in raspbian... for example the groupboxes on the raspberry (raspbian) has no border, and the title of the groupbox has a huge font... also in general fonts sizes seem completely random... is this because I create the gui in windows and the use it in the raspberry?

Answer (score 0):

You can change which Qt style get applied by settings `QT_OVERRIDE_STYLE` environment variable.

Installation usually comes with two styles: Fusion and Windows. Try setting  `QT_OVERRIDE_STYLE` to "Fusion" and see whether that changes it.

There are additional styles in Debian repositories, like this one: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/kde-style-breeze-qt4

Comment: Thanks you, but i try with Fusion but not ok, can you check help me

Comment: if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    w = StartLearning()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())